# How to dismiss Download dialog of Chrome with Selenium (by clicking Cancel)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I can automate the Download action in Chrome with WebDriver. Below is my code to setup Chrome Driver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "/pathToDownloadFolder");
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
// create chrome driver
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The file will be saved in the pathToDownloadFolder.

But I don't want actually to save file. My intention is to automate user's action: Click to download -> Download dialog shown up -> User clicks cancel.

Which option can mirror the Cancel button of Download Dialog?

**EDIT**

I want to download, but not save, because I need to click download button in order to activate another button to click on, so saving file is not necessary, that's why I want to dismiss (or automate action user clicks Cancel when Download dialog apears)

I looked into [Chrome Options](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities), but it seems it is not a possibility with current implementation. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you don't want to download why would you click on the _link to download_ in the first place?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to download, but not save. Long story short, I need to click Download button in order to activate another button to click on. That's why saving file is not mandatory.

Comment: @Ragnarsson You can enable the option **Ask where to save each file before downloading** option under **Downloads** in chrome. So that it will ask the location to download the file. But the system will open up for selecting the location. For doing operations in that window you will have to make use of third party tools. Selenium will not handle that.

Comment: You can always download and delete file.

Comment: @MaciejPulikowski I did it already as a workaround. But I would like to have cleaner way, via Chrome Options, however, it seems impossible at the moment

Comment: What about opening `chrome://downloads/` on new tab and clicking first element matching with `paper-button#cancel`? This will cancel latest download (in your case; there should be one). Then you need to close that tab, and return your main tab and continue on your tests. You may add a helper method which follow these steps.

Comment: @Turcia's approach is what you should try as the chrome pages are also html and it will work for you

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please edit your question and add a series of screenshot snippets illustrating the workflow you want to model?

Answer (score 5):

To enable or to prompt the browser to ask the permission can be done by using below code,

```
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
```

I can see that you have used it. Make it to `true`.

```
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", true);
```

This will ask you to select the location for download. Since after clicking the download, in most cases the system window will open up and this cannot be handled using webdriver. 
For this you have to make use of third party tools like **Sikuli**.

More information for **Sikuli** can be found [here](https://www.guru99.com/sikuli-tutorial.html).

I have not used **Sikuli** , but when I referred about your question. I saw the example given in the above link. May be that will help you.

Comment: Sikuli will work only if the computer is not locked. Sikuli will use the mouse.